# 2d rotation around a point using Canvas and Path

Tags: java, android, math

The issue involves an Android Path shape. It's a triangle that I'm using as an arrow to point towards objects on a screen Canvas. This is for a 2d game. player in the middle of the screen, objects around him and offscreen.

These arrows are supposed to rotate around the center of the screen, with a radius so that they rotate in a circle around the player. The arrows point towards objects that the player needs to move towards.

What I have right now is somewhat working, but the arrows are zipping around the circle at ridiculous speeds. Funny enough, they're pointing in the right direction, but they aren't staying at the right point on the circle. (if arrow is pointing northeast, arrow should be on the northeast part of the circle, etc)

I'm sure it's because of the math. I'm probably using atan2 wrong. Or canvas.translate wrong. Or maybe I shouldn't be using atan2 at all. Help! :)

Here is the code:

```
    // set the shape of our radar blips
    oBlipPath.moveTo(0, -5);
    oBlipPath.lineTo(5, 0);
    oBlipPath.lineTo(0, 5);

    // Paint all the enemies and radar blips!
    for(int i=0; i<iNumEnemies; i++){
        if (oEnemies[i].draw(canvas, (int)worldX, (int)worldY)){

            //calculate the degree the object is from the center of the screen. 
            //(user is the player. this could be done easier using iWidth and iHeight probably)
            //we use a world coordinate system. worldY and worldX are subtracted
            fDegrees = (float)Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2((oEnemies[i].getEnemyCenterY()-worldY)-user.getShipCenterY(), (oEnemies[i].getEnemyCenterX()-worldX)-user.getShipCenterX()));

            canvas.save();

            //get to the center
            canvas.translate((iWidth / 2) , (iHeight / 2) );

            //move a little bit depending on direction (trying to make arrows appear around a circle)
            canvas.translate((float)(20 * Math.cos(fDegrees)), (float)(20* Math.sin(fDegrees)));

            //rotate canvas so arrows will rotate and point in the right direction
            canvas.rotate(fDegrees);

            //draw arrows
            canvas.drawPath(oBlipPath, oBlipPaint);
            canvas.restore();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've got it doing what I wanted, but I don't really know how. I threw in some random numbers until things showed up on the screen the way I wanted. If anyone wants to clue me in as to a better way to do this, I'm all ears.

The code:

```
    // set the shape of our radar blips
    oBlipPath.moveTo(0, -5);
    oBlipPath.lineTo(6, 0);
    oBlipPath.lineTo(0, 5);


    oBlipMatrix.setRotate(45, 0, 0);
    oBlipPath.transform(oBlipMatrix);

    // Paint all the enemies and radar blips!
    for(int i=0; i<iNumEnemies; i++){
        oEnemies[i].draw(canvas, (int)worldX, (int)worldY);
        if (oEnemies[i].bActive){
            //calculate the degree the object is from the center of the screen. 
            //(user is the player. this could be done easier using iWidth and iHeight probably)
            //we use a world coordinate system. worldY and worldX are subtracted
            fDegrees = (float)Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2((oEnemies[i].getEnemyCenterY()-worldY)-(iHeight / 2), (oEnemies[i].getEnemyCenterX()-worldX)-(iWidth / 2)));

            canvas.save();

            //get to the center
            canvas.translate((iWidth / 2 + 50) , (iHeight / 2 + 50) );

            //move a little bit depending on direction (trying to make arrows appear around a circle)
            //canvas.translate((float)(20 * Math.cos(fDegrees)), (float)(20* Math.sin(fDegrees)));

            //rotate canvas so arrows will rotate and point in the right direction
            canvas.rotate(fDegrees-45, -50, -50);

            //draw arrows
            canvas.drawPath(oBlipPath, oBlipPaint);
            canvas.restore();
        }

    }
```

For whatever reason, I have to subtract 45 degrees from the canvas rotation, but add 45 degrees to the matrix rotation of the path shape. It works, but why?! :)

Comment: +1 I'm not the android guy, but this looks better. Note how the rotate  appears to happen _before_ the translate, even though the statement order might suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Affine transformations are are *not* commutative. They are typically applied in an apparent *last-specified-first-applied* order. As an alternative, consider the [`rotate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate%28float,%20float,%20float%29) variation that rotates about a point.

Comment: I got rid of the 2nd translate, and changed the rotate to canvas.rotate(fDegrees, 20, 20); just to quickly test. Good news is, the crazy whirlygig of the arrows stopped and they are pointing in the right direction. kind of. They are on the wrong side of the circle, for one. Arrow pointing northeast, being on the southeast side of the circle, etc. The other issue is that the wrong edge of the arrow is riding along the circle. And if I change the Path() to correct it, then the arrow won't be pointing to the right object.

Comment: I got it working, by subtracting 45 degrees from the angle, and adding 45 degrees in a transform of the path shape. Whatever works, right? I'll post the code tomorrow. I have a limitation because of my low rep count. Have to wait 5 hours or so.